# Translation inside YML string value Symfony

Tags: symfony, yaml, translation

I need to include a translation in my value of YML file in symfony like this

```
        id: meta_title
        optionName: content
        optionValue: '=my.label|trans'
```

Do you have some idea?

Comment: you should use the translation where you output them, not in the configuration itself. so `optionValue` would be a key, not the translation itself.